# Grant security permissions to a database role

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to `grant` security-level permissions to all of the `users` of a certain database `role`. I need them to be able to execute `alter login`, `create login`, `GRANT`, `EXEC sp_addrolemember` and etc.

The only way that I've [found](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/07/24/how-to-impersonate-the-privileges-to-create-a-login-using-the-stored-procedures-using-execute-as-clause.aspx) so far is to add each user to the `security admin` server role with following command:

```
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'userName', 'securityadmin'
```

This is a little cumbersome and I'm not able to perform it for each user. Is there anyway to grant these privileges to a database role? My role, `Administrator` already owns `db_accessadmin` and `db_securityadmin` schemes, but apparently they don't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in SQL 2008, no. Specifically, the ability to create a user-defined server role was introduced in SQL 2012. And since creating and altering logins are server-level permissions, you need, well, a server-level permission.

But all is not lost. You can do what you're looking to do by writing a stored procedure and using module signing. Granted, it's a little more cumbersome for both you and the end user, but the cost may be worth the benefit.